# place button over image (level / z-index)

Tags: ios, xcode

I am at the start of developing iOS applications with xCode 7.2.1 (for iOS 9.2 / Autolayout / Size classes)
I am trying to place a button over an image. When the image is loaded the button is under the image.
Is there a way, like in CSS to set z-index for all elements or a level-viewer like in Photoshop?

Comment: Show some code or something. It's hard to determine what the cause is when we can literally see nothing. There is no z-index but the order in which they are drawn is easy to determine. If I can see what is happening then I can try to help.

Comment: Are you creating the view in Interface Builder or in code? If so could you paste the relevant code/screenshot into your question. I should be able to see what's happening from there :D Thansk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following methods to organise the UIView programmatically:

```
bringSubviewToFront:
sendSubviewToBack:
insertSubview:aboveSubview:
insertSubview:belowSubview:
insertSubview:atIndex:
exchangeSubviewAtIndex:withSubviewAtIndex:
```

[Here you can read up on the above.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW46)

However if you're creating the views with storyboards or in an xib then reordering the items will give you the desired effect.

[image: example ordering]

Here the username UIView is behind the email UIView.

Another way of ordering is mentioned by PudiPudi, you can click the item and change it through the menus.

Another solution is the ordering at which you're adding the views programmatically. Simply changing the order of the, for example, addSubView() function will give a different layering.

Comment: Actually, removed the comment because of the second part of this answer. This may actually fix the problem. If you correctly guessed what the problem is. And from the latest edit you get a plus 1 :D Still, would be nice to know what the actual problem is though.

Comment: I presumed they were adding it within the storyboard. Edited to help with your point though.

Answer (score 0):

You can change its z-index by clicking on your object -> layout menu -> bring to front

i also do think you can change its position by dragging it over other object in the item list on the left in your story